# Book about a teenager programmed to be an assassin and trying to get back at the people responsible

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book a few years back (around 5?). It was part of a multibook series but I have only read one book. 
It's about this teenager who I think had been programmed to be an assassin but then somehow retained his conscience and was out to get the people responsible for that.

I briefly remember a girl, and this one part where he realizes he can ride a horse and then there's a chase too. I think the guy's name was Jim or Jimmy, but not quite. I'm also quite sure he was
either part computer, or had a chip
or something in his brain which had
been programmed to give him a host
of mental and physical abilities
which he retained and used as well
as the series progressed.

Comment: @Richard a few years would be around five years. 

And what makes it scifi is not that he was brainwashed, i'm pretty sure he was either part computer, or had a chip or something in his brain which had been programmed to give him a host of mental and physical abilities which he retained and used as well as the series progressed.

Comment: Where/when is the story set? Is it on a future Earth or in space or what?

Comment: Definitely on earth.
Not too distant future, I guess.

Comment: Just to clarify, you mention a "book" in the second paragraph and a "series" in the second. Do you think this was a multibook series?

Comment: I do recall it being a multibook series, although I have read only one book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the book. "[Jimmy Coates: Assassin?](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/912218.Jimmy_Coates)" by Joe Craig?

I read this book approx 7 years ago, so the details are rusty. Basically, kid gets woken up in the middle of the night, taken from his parents by the government to be an assassin. Has super speed strength, etc. Finds out he is being controlled by the government somehow (like OP I can't remember if it is a chip or what) and tries to destroy the government branch that is controlling him. If I recall correctly, there is a scene in which there is a fight at a restaurant, and he comments about how he would have chosen a Thai place for his base because the chopsticks would make good weapons, when the chef comes out of the kitchen with shish kebobs and turns out to be the owner's bodyguard.

[image]

> *"Who or what is Jimmy Coates? Eleven-year-old Jimmy is on the run. The
>   good news is that he has some sweet new abilities that let him outrun,
>   outjump, and outkick anybody even adults. The bad news is that the
>   mysterious organization that kidnapped Jimmy's parents is after him
>   and he has no idea why. Except that it might have something to do with
>   his new fighting capabilities. And the fact that he might not be
>   entirely human..."*

Comment: It is!! Thank you so much! :)